# Django: rendering forms without custom template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

And I want to use it with `FormView`

```
url(r'^megaform\/', FormView.as_view(form_class=ContactForm, success_url='/thanks/')),
```

Alas, I see the error:

> TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'

It says, that I haven't set the template to render my form with.

Is there a way to render the form **without** a custom template?

Comment: Why would you want a form with no template to render it?

Comment: assuming that is actual code and not just for sake of the example, can I suggest not to put view customization in urls.py ?

Comment: Maybe the reason why you didn't want to specify a template is because you want the form to be rendered in several different places in your website? If that is the case, then a good solution would be to use templates inheritance (using the `extends` and `block` tags) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no there isn't, you must specify a template, that could be something as simple as

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```